# How to stop background of MaterialCardView in Dialog Fragment from being overriden?

Tags: android, material-components-android

I currently have a Dialog Fragment that uses a MaterialCardView as the root with the `@style/Widget.Material3.CardView.Outlined` style. It looks correct in the layout designer in Android Studio. However, when I run the application and inflate the dialog, I the MaterialCardView looks to be using the correct style but with the background colour of `@style/Widget.Material3.CardView.Elevated` instead.

This is how I'm defining the Dialog Fragment's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.CardView.Outlined"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

I've tested this by recreating the same MaterialCardView in my activity and it looks correct so it seems that inflating it as a DialogFragment has broken the background colour somehow? Is there a workaround to this issue?